# Using correctly the @Scope annotation is Spring 3 web application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-3

I recently readed carefully about the spring mvc 3 beans scope, specifically the web ones(session, request and global session) and i have some doubdts:
If i have a controller, why should i annotate him with other scope aside of singleton? I mean, the controllers are supossed to handle the requests and instantiate the view resources of all the app, so why give them a, for instance, session scope? what is the advantage of do that?
Is advisable making the services layer session scoped? 
And finally, is there any convention or good practices that dictates where and when is more convenient the use each one of the web scopes? If there is, can somebody provides me the link or information about it? Not necessary convention or good practices, also your experience about it.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

> I mean, the controllers are supossed to handle the requests and
>   instantiate the view resources of all the app, so why give them a, for
>   instance, session scope?

In an average web application, you have various objects that exist on a per-session basis. Example can be user profile, or some kind of cabinet, or wallet, etc.

To be able to use those objects in service, every time you should get from session, and pass through the service chain. Instead of doing this, of course it is better to have those available in your service, without a need to pass it explicitly.

Really good example (in practice) you can find [here](http://springinpractice.com/2008/05/08/session-scoped-beans-in-spring).

An ideal practical example of request scope bean is `HttpServletRequest`, which should be unique obviously for each request, therefore it is request scoped and created for each request.

From my experience, without any explicit need for a case, you don't need to bother yourself with changing scopes. It is not without reason that default scope is Singleton, it is by purpose - because in most of the applications and basic scenarios you need beans as singleton. However as your main concern was with Session and Request scopes, the above examples are cases which you need often in web application.

Comment: Thanks, really good your answer, and very clear the examples you provided